# Dynamic javascript event calendar with multi-day event support

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, calendar

Okay, so I've been banging my head against this problem for a while now (months). But I can't seem to find a simple solution to creating a calendar with Javascript that allows my to dynamically add events to it AND support multi-day events.

My first approach was using divs with year-month-day associated IDs so I can easily add events, the issue here is that there is no way to support multi-day events, adding single day events is easy though.

My latest approach was to dissect the google calendar, they apparently use tables, which is a good solution as it supports multi-day event blocks easily (using colspan), however adding/rendering events on a table seems to be an entirely different feat, as I can't simply add them to a column/cell block. I have to generate a new row, and then if it is a multi-day event that pushes events down, I would have to re-render those parts of the calendar as well.
Here is a link to my current "dynamic" approach that I've been working on: https://r3dux.com/css/caldyn.php

and here is a static version to show what it is supposed to look like with events on it: https://r3dux.com/css/cal.php

I do NOT want to use a third-party calendar of any sort. I want to do this with pure Javascript, NO Jquery or other frameworks.

If you could simply give me some suggestions or different ways to approach this, that would be super helpful.

The basic requirements are that it has multi-day event support, can be adapted into a "week" view (only shows the current and next week), and allows me to display individual start/end times for each day of an event. I also need to somehow support scheduling events across Daylight Savings Time and Standard time. Like, if it is currently DST and a schedule an event in the future when it's STD, I want the time the user selected during DST to be when the event is scheduled, so the time doesn't change an hour when the switch happens.

Comment: you could try dissecting how they do it in this [jquery-week-calendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar)

Comment: It doesn't seem to support multi-day events. also, it's a detailed week view which is not what I'm looking for right now

Answer (score 2):

First off, I would consider refactoring the `renderCalendar` function - it's huge! It cannot be easy to imagine, let alone implement, multi day events with that code.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peLDD/) based on some old, unfinished code (with which the goal was to create a google-like calendar) that can perhaps serve as a suggestion on how to do it. It's very far from what you want, but maybe you can draw some ideas from it.

It is written without any third party libraries, but it requires a newish browser. The `map`, `some`, etc functions can be easily [polyfilled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) however.

The `Calendar`, `Day` and `Event` prototypes serves as a way to avoid huge methods. I could e.g. remove the logic in the rendering methods to completely follow an MVC pattern, which eases development.

To dynamically add events, push an `Event` to `Calendar.events` and call `Calendar.render()`. It already "supports" multi day events and single events, but it most definitely needs some work.

Good luck!